# Would faulty wiring let you access the internet but fail to let you find a domain controller on the LAN?

Tags: domain-controller, ethernet, wiring

I have been having a random issue regarding joining a domain at my workplace. II am a programmer, not a network tech, so I struggle with these issues and would like my suspicion confirmed

In this case, I've been struggling with a workstation that will not allow our application, which resides on a Win 2003 server, to be accessed from the workstation.

One of the things I tried was to remove the workstation from the domain and then attempt to rejoin it. When I tried to rejoin it, I received a message saying the domain controller could not be found. I confirmed my connection by ensuring I could access sites on the internet. Also I was able to access folders on the same server where the domain controller resides.

I had a similar issue with another PC that was in a building a few hundred yards from where the server is housed, and I had a gut feeling it may have something to do with the Ethernet wiring between the PC and a hub there, so I had it replaced and then afterward I was able to access the domain controller. Problem solved.

Now with this second PC, replacing the wiring isn't so easy, as it is hung inside the wall with no plate to plug in to.

So I disconnected the PC and brought over to my own office, where I have several cables run for times where I need to do upgrades and re-installs. There, the workstation found the domain controller in a second or two and allowed me to connect without issue.

So I'm asking, should I consider faulty wiring to be the problem here?

Thanks.

Marshall

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that's the problem here.

Comment: Could it be a bad port on the router, then? The only real difference when connected in the users office vs connected from my office is the router. We use 2 32 port routers, and there are 2 hubs between it and my connection. The connection in the users office is connected directly to one of the routers.

Answer (score 4):

Look at your DNS. Involve the people that *are* responsible for the AD domain. Most AD-related problems like you're describing are DNS related.

Hint - the only DNS servers that a client should be using are the ones that contain the AD records. Most of the time, those will also be the domain controllers.

Comment: That is an unfortunate aspect of my job. There is no one other than me or my boss here that works IT. My boss handles most things to do with AD and DNS. And I've told him about this and all he said was that if the internet is accessible, the there is no problem with the wiring. I can look at the DNS server (same machine as the AD and our SQL server), but any changes have to be approved and made by him. I just don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: Speaking of the SQL Server, after getting the PC joined using the cabling in my office, I am still getting the '"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server' error when I try to run our app. Doesn't matter what user I log in as.

Comment: Tell us what the IP address(es) of the DC are, and what DNS server(s) the client is configured to use. `ipconfig /all` from each of them would show that.

Comment: My DNS server uses 192.168.16.1

Comment: You really didn't comprehend what I wrote, at all.

Comment: Not surprising. And my edit above failed as I got distracted by my boss and didn't get to save it until just now. I'm posting it now.

We have only 1 DNS and 1 DC here.
I assume that 'from each of them' means the client and the server? 

My DNS server address is 192.168.16.1
All our clients are manually configured to use this.

Excuse my ignorance, but for the DC IP address, do I need to run the command from the server itself? From my PC I show a DHCP server, which is outside our subnet (Not in 192.168.16.*) I believe it points to the router used by our T1 lines.  The Gateway is 192.168.16.254

Comment: run `ipconfig /all` on your DC and your client. Post that into your question via editing.